# RegEx help: Matching a set of words unless they are preceded by specific keywords

Tags: regex

Looking for some regex help.  I need to match words/phrases e.g. "confidential" "top secret" "sensitive" unless they are preceded by other words, for example: "contain" on the same line ..

"This email may contain confidential information"  - this would not match

"Please see the attached confidential document" - would match because "contain" does not appear before the keyword "confidential" on the link.

I looked at using negative lookbehind but it's limited by width, so it would not work.  In my case, the preceding words can appear several words before the keyword I am trying to match.  Thanks!

Comment: Providing the actual code you are using is very helpful -- for example, there are several dialects of RegEx and it is unclear which one you are using.

Comment: This is a good question, why the votes to close?

Comment: Voting to close because: no regex dialect given, no valid examples of what was tried.

Comment: No @Kuba. he "demonstrates a minimal understanding of the problem" by his lookbehind width comment. More understanding than you apparently :) - Also regex dialect is unnecessary unless there are issues specific to an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You would think lookbehind, but it actually needs to be lookahead:

```
/^((?!contain).)*(confidential|top secret|sensitive)/
```

Because of the lookbehind fixed-wdth requirement.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this almost works the way I need, but it grabs the entire text, and I just want to grab the keywords unless they are preceded by other keywords.

This is actually for RSA DLP, a corp compliance platform, and I am not exactly sure what implementation of regex they are using.  It is all gui driven.

Comment: To turn a capture group `()` into a non-capture group `(?:)` just add the `?:` so `/^(?:(?!foo).)*(bar)/`